# How to give link to Login Page in MVC 5 existing project?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an existing sample project in asp.net-MVC-5 with C#. The sample Project Working Fine. But the problem is, whenever I run the Project, the project will leads to the page,where my cursor was in. For Example, If I am editing in home-Index page means, while running-the project starts from Home/Index page only. But I want to start from Login page only. How to give correct link?

My codings are below:

**My _viewstart as**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

**My _Layout as**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()      
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**My Login Page is in the path
~Views/Account/Login.cshtml.
My Login design as follows:**

```
@using M.Models
@model LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
     Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Log in</title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/adminlte/components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/adminlte/components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/adminlte/components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/adminlte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/adminlte/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css">
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/adminlte/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition login-page">
    <div class="login-box">
        <div class="login-logo">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Logo.jpg")" alt="HRMS" width="360" /><br />
        </div>
        <!-- /.login-logo -->
        <div class="login-box-body">
            <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <div class="input-icon">
                        @*<i class="fa fa-user"></i>*@
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "form-control placeholder-no-fix", @placeholder = "Username", @maxlength = "50" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <div class="input-icon">
                        @*<i class="fa fa-user"></i>*@
                        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control placeholder-no-fix", @placeholder = "Password", @maxlength = "50" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @*<div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>*@
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-8">

                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                </div>               
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.login-box-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-box -->
    <!-- jQuery 3 -->
    <script src="~/Content/adminlte/components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <script src="~/Content/adminlte/components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <script src="~/Content/adminlte/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('input').iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
                radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
                increaseArea: '20%' /* optional */
            });
        });</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a setting in the Visual Studio project. Go to the Project properties and look on the Web section. Change your Start Action from Current Page to Start URL and fill in the URL you want, which will most likely be your Project Url. You can copy it from there.

Comment: while tick correct answer it shows that need to wait 3 mins to choose correct answer. Once 3 mins over , I will tick the answer sir. Thank you